# How to disable future dates,months and year in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

How to hide the future dates in UIDatePicker for user choosing only past and current year of birthdays.

I search lot of source but I can't get the desired result.

Here is my code,

```
 dateofBirthDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];

    dateofBirthDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [dateofBirthDatePicker setBackgroundColor:DATE_PICKER_GRAY_COLOR];

//    UILabel *label = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class],[UIDatePicker class], nil];
//    label.font = HELVETICA_NEUE(24);
//    label.textColor = GREEN_COLOR;
    [dateofBirthDatePicker addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(LabelChange:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    dateofbirthTextField.inputView = dateofBirthDatePicker;
    [self datePickerToolBar];
}

- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dateofbirthTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateofBirthDatePicker.date]];
}
```

If any body know the solution kindly give the suggestion. I really appreciate to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift 2:

`self.datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()`

In Swift 3:

`self.datePicker.maximumDate = Date()`

Answer (score 65):

Here is the simple code to prevent future date selection:

```
dateofBirthDatePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date];
```

In Swift :

```
dateofBirthDatePicker.maximumDate = Date()
```

Answer (score 9):

**In Swift 4.0.3    Xcode 9**

Hide Future Date

```
self.picker.maximumDate = Date()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use setMaximumDate: and setMinimumDate: on UIDatePicker object:

```
[dateofBirthDatePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]]; // The max date will be today

// Optional you can set up min date as well
[dateofBirthDatePicker setMinimumDate:yourMinDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:1];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:-30];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI inline DatePicker:

```
DatePicker("Select Date", selection: $date, in: ...Date())
```